# How to use streamController to Flutter push notification?

Tags: flutter, push-notification, stream, firebase-cloud-messaging

hello I just want to ask help, Is there anyone who can help me apply stream to flutter application whenever I receive a push notifications? I haven't found any links related to what I want.

in short I want to listen to the data received from the FCM and update the screen. thanks

Answer (score -1):

Please refer this for notification streams
https://pub.dev/packages/action_broadcast

thanks